# LUKS шифрование каталогов/файлов Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, decrypt

Такой вопрос, можно ли зашифровать конкретные файлы и каталоги в ОС ubuntu, чтобы обезопасить доступ к ним из другой операционной системы?
Просто сразу возникает вопрос, если шифровать конфиги, будут ли корректно работать службы эти конфигов и надо ли этих расшифровывать по одному? Или, можно ли автоматически выполнять расшифровку этих файлов/ каталогов при загрузке ОС? Если не LUKS, то может какие-либо другие инструменты.
В сети натыкаюсь только на предварительно шифрованных диск , на который потом уже накатывается ось, а пароль на флешке.

Comment: Я использую ecryptfs, который предоставляет каталог ~/Private, в который можно поскидывать секретные файлы, а потом ссылаться на них симлинками. У меня в убунте так зашифрованы конфиги Firefox и SSH, вроде норм работает (но про другие ОС и про службы конфигов не знаю, а автоматическая расшифровка это по-моему немножко глупо)

Comment: то есть, при запуске лисы или ssh запрашивается пароль для расшифровки?

Comment: При запуске лисы или ssh будет ошибка, пока я вручную не запущу ecryptfs-mount-private и не введу пароль — лично меня такое положение дел вполне устраивает